# Inconsistent Function of Apple Mail Rule Script

Tags: macos, email, applescript, rules, macos-sonoma

In addition to built in Rule options being buggy already. Sounds and Bouncing Icon works, but only one color rule will apply (either text or background). So my Rule to set the text to blue if my full name is addressed applies, but the set background color in the Alert Rule doesn't. Although it does run the script at the end, it just glitches in it.

The goal of the script is to prompt an actual alert on my computer whenever I'm emailed an alert from my bank or whatever. Sometimes spam gets caught in the filter, so I include the option to Open, Delete, and Remind Me Later. Which snoozes it for 10 minutes in case I'm working on something and can't get to it right away. Here's the **body** of the script:

```
    -- Reminders Loop
    repeat while true -- Allows snoozing alerts as long as the user wants to.
        set reminders to {} -- Keeps track of emails to remind about. 
        -- Display Alert 
        repeat with email in emails -- For each email that triggered this rule:
            -- Prompt user for what to do.
            set choice to button returned of (display alert "Alert" message "You've been sent an alert via email: " & (the subject of the email) as critical buttons {"Remind Me Later", "Delete", "Open"} default button "Remind Me Later")
            if choice = "Open" then
                open the email
            else if choice = "Delete" then
                delete the email
            else -- add it to the reminders. 
                set the end of reminders to the email
            end if
        end repeat
        -- Check For Reminders  
        if reminders is {} then -- If there's nothing left that the user wants to be reminded about:
            exit repeat -- End the script.
        else -- Otherwise:
            set emails to reminders -- Only remind the user about the emails the user wanted to be reminded about. 
            delay 600 -- Wait 10 minutes before going through the alerts again.
        end if
    end repeat
```

The alert itself looks like this:

[image: Alert]

The issue is that it seems to forget what the iterator "email" refers to after the first time it's called, but only when using the script in a Rule wrapped between

```
-- Header
using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages emails -- in mailboxes boxes for rule theRule﻿
```

and

```
        -- Footer 
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

. The correct subject is displayed, but all of the options affect a different email. If Remind Me Later is used the subject of that different email will show instead, and from then on all of the options will correctly apply to that mistakenly referenced other email.

In the test case where I was emailing myself, my email was automatically being filed under Known Senders (folder) by another rule. Being the newest email it was the first item in that folder. The email that is referenced in its place after that first use of its subject text is the first item in the Inbox folder. I tried doing things like saving a reference to its `id`, `message id`, `mailbox`, et cetera, and referencing it from that data, but it seems to still somehow change reference to the 1st item in the Inbox rather than the Known Senders folder. When I tested it by wrapping it between

```
-- Header
tell application "Mail"
    set emails to selection
```

and

```
    -- Footer
end tell
```

with a selection of emails it works as expected; maintaining reference to the correct email(s) from the initial list that was given.

At least it's not as broken as the Autoreply Rule option. It does send a reply, but it's completely blank; failing to contain the content set in the popup when making the Rule. There doesn't seem to be any mechanism to prioritize rules over other rules which could simultaneously apply to a message either, but with some over complicating of the rules this can be worked around.